# Unable to wrap my head around the implementation of Mediator pattern

Tags: typescript, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to learn Design patterns using OOP by building a game.

The game will have a predator and a prey. When a predator comes near the prey, it starts eating it. Until now, I have come so far.

I think I will need a mediator pattern here as there will be one alien (predator) and multiple humans (preys) walking on a given area of the game. The area being the mediator.

I won't be going in to the graphics part yet, but I just want to run on the command line like `human1.reduceHP()` that will reduce `human1`'s HP. But, the condition for this code to happen is missing (I believe in the form of the Mediator).

However, I am unable to wrap my head around the actual implementation. I have come this far with the following:

1. `Organism` as the base class and `IEatable` as interface.
2. `Human` and `Alien` are the concrete implementations of the `Organism`.
3. `Human` is `IEatable`.

```
export abstract class Organism {
  abstract maxHP: number;
  abstract currentHP: number;
  abstract canHit: boolean;

  isStomachFull = false;
  stomachCapacity = 100;

  reduceHp() {
    if (this.currentHP > 0) {
      this.currentHP -= 1;
    }
  }

  recoverHp() {
    if (this.maxHP < this.currentHP) {
      this.currentHP += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```
interface IEatable {
  isEatable: boolean;
}
```

```
import { Organism } from '../abstract/Organism';

export class Alien extends Organism {
  maxHP: number;
  currentHP: number;
  canHit: boolean;

  constructor(hp, canHit) {
    super();
    this.maxHP = hp;
    this.canHit = canHit;
    this.currentHP = this.maxHP;
  }
}
```

```
import { Organism } from '../abstract/Organism';

export class Human extends Organism implements IEatable {
  maxHP: number;
  currentHP: number;
  canHit: boolean;
  isStomachFull: boolean;
  stomachCapacity: number;
  isEatable: boolean;

  constructor(hp, canHit, isEatable) {
    super();
    this.maxHP = hp;
    this.canHit = canHit;
    this.currentHP = this.maxHP;
    this.isEatable = isEatable;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with "java"?

Comment: Because I am trying a prototype in Typescript. The actual implementation is going to be in Java.

Comment: Someone already untagged "java" but if you think the tag should stay, could you [edit] the question body to make it clear how that relates?  I doubt it does relate, though, since I don't think you're trying to discuss the future "actual" implementation.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense. It's ok if this doesn't have a Java tag.

Comment: In this use case the predator could simply loop through all the prey and eat the ones that are closest. I think a Mediator makes more sense if there are several predators. Then the top level code can decide which predator eats which prey.

Comment: So, actually the plan is to add more predators who are going to be multiple players.